# Unable to Update Immutable list item value

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I'm trying to update an immutable list using the following code.But the list is unaltered.Why does this happen?

```
private gaparameterlist: Immutable.List<ConfigurationConstant>;
private updateItem(globalparameter: enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters, event) {
    let item = this.gaparameterlist.find(x => x.key === globalparameter);
    item.value = event.target.value;
    this.gaparameterlist.set(0, item);
}
```

Comment: I would assume that it being immutable prevents it from being changed? Perhaps creating a new list would work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Immutable.List.set()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/set) does not modify the original list but returns a copy with new value.

So you need to save the result of `this.gaparameterlist.set(0, item)`:

```
private updateItem(globalparameter: enums.IASamplingGlobalParameters, event) {
    let item = this.gaparameterlist.find(x => x.key === globalparameter);
    item.value = event.target.value;
    this.gaparameterlist = this.gaparameterlist.set(0, item); // save new immutable list returned by list.set()
}
```